# Sharing SSH keys

Tags: ssh

I use a private SSH key and passwordless entry for a number of user accounts on a server that hosts a number of websites.

I use the same private key for each user account. (because I'm lazy? or is that the "right" way).

I now want to authorise another trusted computer in a different part of the country. If I copy the contents of my ~/.ssh onto that machine will that work without any other set up?

Will both machines be able to maintain a connection at the same time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work, and both machines should be able to maintain a connection at the same time - I've had to copy my `~/.ssh` directory a few times before when hard drives have crashed.

Answer (score 37):

*Update:* as an additional security recommendation, you should generate a new set of keys for a new machine and send your new public key out to the various hosts you use it on, rather than copying your private keys. If you're just moving everything to a new computer however, you can take your keys with you, but remember to destroy them securely on the old computer.

---

The correct answer is to copy your `.ssh` directory from the old machine to the new. This part is easy (`scp -r .ssh user@newmachinehost:~` will do fine—or you can type the keys in character-by-character, up to you).

**BUT**—I think the missing link to answer this question is what you have to do *after* you copy your private keys to the new machine.

I had to run the following for each key (I have 3 separate keys for various organizations)

```
ssh-add .ssh/[key-filename]
```

If the filename argument is omitted, `id_rsa` is assumed.

Once you do this to each key (and enter they key's passphrase if required; it will prompt you), ssh will be able to use those keys to authenticate.

Otherwise, no amount of copying will do much. SSH will ignore the keys in .ssh until they are explicitly used (via `ssh -i [keyfilename] ...`).

Comment: Thank you so much for this info. I've been cracking my head against my desk for days wondering why everything else was in place, but I still couldn't get my key to work. Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

Comment: How come ssh-add isn't permanent, it gets forgotten upon reboot?

Comment: ssh-add just adds the key to the current environment. If you want it to stick, check out ssh-agent, which runs as a daemon and handles all your keys under one master password. Mac OSX has a more user-friendly analogue of ssh-agent, Keychain, which unlocks your SSH keys on login and actually runs and manages ssh-agent in the background for ssh to use seamlessly. Neat. Various others exist for Linux window managers, but they all just manage a running ssh-agent.

Answer (score 7):

Copying `~/.ssh` between systems is fine so long as it's limited to just files like `authorized_keys`, `config`, and `known_hosts`.  If you want two hosts to be able to access each other, each host needs its own private SSH key, which must then be added to the other host's `authorized_keys` file.

**It is *not* a good idea to copy private keys across systems!**

Think of real world secrets.  Each person who learns the secret increases the chance of it being revealed.

Every time you copy your private key to a new system, you increase your risk of exposure because **copied private keys are less secure than the weakest system they live on** (because the other systems aren't invulnerable either).

If your laptop gets stolen, you need to revoke all private keys (and saved passwords) that were stored there.  This becomes problematic when the only way to log into servers is with that very key.  You'd better remember to generate a new key on your desktop and install it on each system you revoke the old key from!

Now consider your desktop gets hacked and somebody steals your private key without your knowledge.  Perhaps you had shared this key between your work laptop and your personal desktop, but your desktop doesn't really need access to your work system (because you have good work/life balance).  That attacker can now access your work system even without having compromised your laptop.  The infosec team at work forces you to hand over your laptop so they can audit it, but after a week of analysis, they find nothing.  Not so fun.

These may seem far-fetched and unlikely, especially if you're not a prime target (e.g. an executive or sysadmin), but it's just a good practice, especially given how easy it is to create new keys for each system and install their public keys on each appropriate server.  (Consider one of the myriads of config/dotfile propagation systems if this seems daunting.)

Additionally, it means you'll upgrade the security of each key to meet the standards as they improve.  As you retire old systems and remove their keys, you rotate out their weaker keys.  (And if some trash picker finds your old laptop and undeletes your keys, they won't grant any access.)

Comment: Is it acceptable to have the same ssh key on two machines if DNS can under certain circumstances resolve to either device?  Not having the same ssh key is causing all sorts of problems.

Comment: Not in my opinion, unless the systems actually sync each other's data (including authentication bits, since in that case one system's compromise is each other's as well). You can solve that with `StrictHostKeyChecking yes` and `CheckHostIP no` (for just that FQDN!) and then manually add each host's keys to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. If you ask this as an SO question, please link to it here and I'll give you a fuller answer. That's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is secure so long as you don't share you private key. Just place the public key in the remote machine's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file for passwordless entry. Don't share the private key though.

The keys are just for authentication. You can log on as many times as you wish with the same key, so long as you can log on with that private key once.

Comment: Not quite what I'm asking – I have passwordless entry set up with a remote machine, but I want to authorize more than one machine with the same private key.

Comment: That's exactly what I answered for. You take your public key and you place it in any remote machine you wish to access. You're not sharing a private key here, you're sharing a public key. And this is why public keys are public: to share them.

Comment: It's not that I want my computer to access two other computers, it's that I want two computers to be able to access one other. I share my pub key with a computer I want to access, but if I want another computer to access one I can already access, it needs a private key. Normally I'd make another private key for that one, but I have around 50 accounts set up already, and want to avoid adding the new public key to all those. If that makes sense!

Comment: Ah. I'm sorry then, I misunderstood you.