# Is there a way to sync ssh directory keys across multiple devices?

Tags: ssh

I have two windows and one Ubuntu devices that I regularly work with, and I was wondering if there is a way for me to sync the ssh directory for each of the device so that they all have the same ssh key, config, and authorized_key? For windows I'm using the Ubuntu terminal from Microsoft store.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't recommend this, but it has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520578/sharing-ssh-keys). See the answer by @trisweb about scp. Hope this helps

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but scp only work when the other machine is on right? Is there a way to do it so that it's like one drive or dropbox that syncs across different devices when it boots?

Comment: true, well there is NFS, you may need to add ntfs support to your ubuntu machine to get it working. Heres a link to point you that way:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/717451/how-to-use-nfs-to-share-a-mounted-drive